# Is there any way to convert the time column of a dataset from string to time or any suitable format, without actually changing the content?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Is there any way to convert the time column of a dataset from string to time or any suitable format, without actually changing the content?

[image]

Comment: without changing the content? not sure what you mean... you want to change it but not changing it?

Answer (score 1):

We have two options at hand for time dtypes

**Sample Input**

```
data= pd.DataFrame({
    'last_visit_time':['16:08:02', '04:14:05']
}, dtype='string')
```

#### To Timedelta

```
data['last_visit_time'] = pd.to_timedelta(data['last_visit_time'])
```

**Output**

```
    last_visit_time
0   0 days 16:08:02
1   0 days 04:14:05
```

#### To datetime

```
data['last_visit_time'] = pd.to_datetime(data.last_visit_time)
```

**Output**

```
    last_visit_time
0   2021-05-02 16:08:02
1   2021-05-02 04:14:05
```

Applying `format` to datetime will result at year `1900`

```
data['last_visit_time'] = pd.to_datetime(data.last_visit_time, format='%H:%M:%S')
```

**Output**

```
    last_visit_time
0   1900-01-01 16:08:02
1   1900-01-01 04:14:05
```

Comment: the time delta solution is nice :D almost "not changing the content" :D but still it's pretty stupid (not your fault, authors)

Comment: you just aggregated two existing answers... i posted `timedelta` and frustrated_biostatistician posted `datetime`

Comment: There are only two ways sir, you have used apply function for it. I'm not here for points but to share knowledge in best of my capacity. If you want please modify your answer to use to_timedelta() and I will delete my answer.

Comment: Just to add, you used apply function to apply timedelta and frustrated_biostatistician use format arg.

Comment: @Utsav feel free to keep your answer. generally the SO etiquette is to make small suggestions as comments instead of aggregating other answers with small modifications

Comment: oh okay. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this -

```
data['last_visit_time'] = pd.to_datetime(data.last_visit_time).dt.time
```

Notice `dt.time` at the end to extract the time.

Comment: Just a thought, .dt.time might result in 'Object' type and currently the data is of 'string' type.

Comment: ah good idea +1, i think this is actually the closest to the OP's request of "not changing the content" while still having a `datetime` object

Comment: This solution does the job but the dtype is object, can it be somehow made to  datetime64[ns] with the same time format. Not sure if it can be done but looking for possibilities.

Comment: It’s in correct time format. If you try to add string value in this particular column it’ll throw the error = TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.time' and ‘str’. I think datetime.time object in pandas is just shown as object data type. But, IMO it’ll work for you

Answer (score 0):

Try iterating through each string and do `string.split(":") # returns list`
This gives you a list with 3 items, with hour time and second respectively. Then you can form into another format.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "without changing the content", so apologies if this isn't what you're looking for... But to convert your column example to datetime format, you could do:

```
data['last_visit_time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['last_visit_time'], format="%H:%M:%S")
```

The column values should stay the same, but the dtype will change to datetime instead of string.